# iOS NSKeyedArchiver -- NSMutableDictionary coming back as NSPlaceholderDictionary?

Tags: ios, encoding, nsmutabledictionary, nskeyedarchiver, archiving

I have a large and complex object graph.  I have implemented NSCoding to archive and unarchive the object graph.  Normally, everything works fine.  But under certain highly reproducible circumstances, an NSMutableDictionary that I archive gets unarchived as an NSPlaceholderDictionary.  This is a private subclass of NSMutableDictionary and represents an uninitialized dictionary.  It does not respond to any of the usual NSDictionary methods.

I am wondering if anyone has run across a similar problem.  If so, were you able to solve it?  And how?

EDIT: One thing I can say about the circumstances is that the dictionary itself is deeply nested, with lots of contained dictionaries and arrays.  And deep inside it is a pointer to another object that is in the process of being created.  The object graph is a tree.  Most objects in the tree contain weak references to their parents.  The problem occurs at n layers deep in the tree.  At the time of the crash, the stack looks something like this [I've simplified it]:

```
0. crash because dictionary is a placeholder
1. depth n initWithCoder -- decode a deep and large dictionary which, prior to encoding contained reference to object at depth n+4.  Said object has not yet been decoded.
2. Apple methods 
3. depth n+1 initWithCoder -- decode reference to parent
4. 38 frames of apple methods for very deeply nested dictionary
5. depth n-1 initWithCoder -- decode a deeply nested dictionary.  Among other things, the dictionary contains a reference to the level n+1 object [inside a lot of nested dictionaries and arrays]
6. Apple methods
7. depth n-2 object initWithCoder -- decode reference to array containing its children
```

Comment: could you explain the certain highly reproducible circumstances? And maybe provide the encoding and decoding of the object graph

Comment: unfortunately not; the app is still in development and under NDA.  There is no obvious problem with the data when I inspect them in a text editor (encoding produces a plist file.)

Comment: understandable. Could you explain the reproducible circumstance without giving anything away?

Comment: are your keys in the Dictionary all `NSString`'s?

Comment: Yes.  But the values are lots of different things.

Comment: just want to make sure I understand. You are encoding an object graph that consists of many objects (used loosely). One of these objects is an NSMutableDictionary, that is archived using `NSKeyedArchiver` and upon unarchiving, it is of type NSPlaceolderDictionary. Is this right?